# ng-admin : Difference between add and edit view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-admin

I yuse the smart ng-admin javascript framework for my admin

I want to have some difference between edit and add view ..

for instance, i want to add some fields in edit view : I would like to do someting like that :

```
var addViewFields = recipe.creationView().fields([
       nga.field('title'),
       nga.field('guest')]);
var editViewFields = angular.copy(addViewFields);
```

and i would like to do something like that :

```
editViewFiels.push(nga.field('pictureUpload','file').etc ...)
```

Could you folks help with that ? Thanks in advance, have a nice day coding and doing some smart things.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually refer the the fields on another view with the syntax `entity.viewName().fields()`. So in your case it would be:

```
recipe.editionView.fields([
    recipe.creationView().fields(),
    nga.field('pictureUpload', 'file'),
    ...
])
```